# Home Work: Read a file into a pointer-to-pointer char (char**)

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I hate to put home work on stackoverflow. Sorry in advance.

I have to write a function that fits the following declaration

```
char ** read_maze(char *filename, int *rows, int *cols )
```

The funtion I have written so far is

```
char ** read_maze(char *filename, int *rows, int *cols )
{
  ifstream maze(filename);
  maze >> *rows >> *cols;
  char * contents[] = new char * [*rows * *cols];
  for (int r = 0; r < *rows; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < *cols; c++) {
      if (!maze.eof())
        maze >> contents[r][c];
    }
  }
  return contents;
}
```

The problem that I am having is that accessing/writing to the char-array `contents` is giving me a segmentation fault. I've tried all sorts of different accessors and I can't seem to prevent a segfault from happening.

I've tried googling how to access point-pointer chars in c++, but I couldn't find anything entirely substantial.

Things I've tried: *contents[r * c], *(contents+r*c), *((contents[r])+c), and many others.

How can I read a file into a `char **`?

Thanks

Comment: You have also to initialize `contents[r]`, or use `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: What are the rows and cols variables? And I may be wrong, but it looks like contents is being initialized to a `**char[]`. You need to allocate char[x] before you can assign it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you need is:

```
std::ifstream maze(filename);
std::size_t rowCount, colCount;
maze >> rowCount >> colCount;
std::vector<std::vector<char>> content(rowCount, std::vector<char>(colCount));
for (auto &columns : content) {
    for (auto& c : columns) {
        maze >> c;
    }
}
```

if really you want to use `new []`:

```
char** read_maze(const char* filename, int& rowCount, int& colCount)
{
    std::ifstream maze(filename);
    maze >> rowCount>> colCount;
    char** contents = new char* [rowCount];
    for (int r = 0; r != rowCount; ++r) {
        contents[r] = new char[colCount];
        for (int c = 0; c != colCount; ++c) {
            if (!maze.eof()) {
                maze >> contents[r][c];
            }
        }
    }
    return contents;
}
```

But then you have to destroy your content yourself with `delete[]`:

```
void delete_maze(char** contents, int rowCount)
{
    for (int r = 0; r != rowCount; ++r) {
        delete [] contents[r];
    }
    delete [] contents;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately as stated this is homework so I can't use a vector

Comment: For the record I did have to modify you're method declaration a little bit (to take pointers), as well as not to use a `const` filename (not sure why, that should be fine?) Other than that it worked great!

Comment: As you don't modify `filename` content, it should be `const char*` (but you have to match bad prototype :-/). Else you may not use (const) literal string to call `read_maze` (as `read_maze("my_path.txt", &rowCount, &colCount)`) but have to use some buffer which contains the path...

Comment: this is a college C++ professor. My life consists entirely of matching bad prototype :/

Answer (score 0):

With this line you have a pointer to a pointers of chars.

```cpp
  char **contents = new char * [*rows * *cols];
```

Now you have a lot of char pointers which you have to allocate memory.
You can do it like this:

```cpp
for (int r = 0; r < *rows; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < *cols; c++) {
           contents[r][c] = new char[SIZE_OF_STRING];
    }
}
```

Or you can instead use `std::string` to avoid C-Style char*-pointers.

Comment: Yes, you have to execute the this loop before your for loop. But something you have to consider if you want to write something you have to do it with ofstream. With ifstream you only read stuff.